# Refactoring a rigid code to eliminate if-else statement of checking instanceOf

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, refactoring

Good day everyone,

I have a question regarding to refactoring a piece of code. The classes are structured as:

```
abstract class A
class A1 extends class A
class A2 extends class A
class A3 extends class A

abstract class AdditionalStuff {
    abstract void function(); 
}
class AdditionalStuffForA1 extends AdditionalStuff
class AdditionalStuffForA2 extends AdditionalStuff
class AdditionalStuffForA3 extends AdditionalStuff

class Implementation {
    List<A> aList; 
    .... //add A1, A2, A3 to aList

    AdditionalStuff aS;

    for (A instance: aList) {
        if(instance instanceOf A1)
            aS = new AdditionalStuffForA1();
        else if(instance instanceOf A2)
            aS = new AdditionalStuffForA2();
        else
            aS = new AdditionalStuffForA3();

        aS.function()
    }

}
```

The code above is rigid I think, because everytime when a new class An (for example A4 and AdditionalStuffForA4) is added, It's a must to modify the if else statements too.

I thought about using Decorator Pattern, but now I think Decorator Pattern cannot solve my problem. I would like to ask, could you please suggest me a way to refactoring the code above to eliminate the use of if-else statement? (Note that, I cannot add functions of AdditionalStuff to be inside A because they are used differently)

Comment: Does the `AdditionalStuff ` abstract class holds state?

Comment: Hey Aris, thank you for the comment. I am new to Object oriented programming language. Could you please tell me what is the meaning of holding state? Does it mean AdditionalStuff contains fields?

Comment: What he means is: does `AdditionalStuff` have any instance fields or does it just provide the method declaration `void function()` (in which case if could be an interface instead)?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, it contains a lot of other fields and other concrete functions too. I just simplify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to this. But the simplest answer to extend your existing implementation would look something like this

```
abstract class A { 
    public abstract AdditionalStuff getAdditionalStuff();
}

class A1 extends class A { 
    @Override
    public AdditionalStuff getAdditionalStuff() {
       return new AdditionalStuffA1();
    }
}

class A2 extends class A { 
    @Override
    public AdditionalStuff getAdditionalStuff() {
       return new AdditionalStuffA2();
    }
}

class A3 extends class A { 
    @Override
    public AdditionalStuff getAdditionalStuff() {
       return new AdditionalStuffA3();
    }
}

abstract class AdditionalStuff {
    abstract void function(); 
}
class AdditionalStuffForA1 extends AdditionalStuff
class AdditionalStuffForA2 extends AdditionalStuff
class AdditionalStuffForA3 extends AdditionalStuff

class Implementation {
    List<A> aList; 
.... //add A1, A2, A3 to aList

    AdditionalStuff aS;

    for (A instance: aList) {
        aS = instance.getAdditionalStuff();
        aS.function()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you George for your help.
But I don't think I can modify the A, A1, A2, A3 classes. Because there are some scenarios that just use A, A1, A2, A3 classes without any AdditionalStuff.

Comment: Then you would return null for them. And you would check if aS is not null before calling the aS.function()

Comment: If you the owner of these classes A1, A2, A3, ....then you wouldn't have a problem adding this extra method. Any class that doesn't have a corresponding AdditionalStuff then they would return null in the overridden method

Comment: @Lup Did this answer your question?

Comment: @Geoge Arokiam: Hey George, thank you so much. I think your suggestion fits the code implementation the best.

Comment: @Lup In fact you can return null from the base class. That way you don't need to override for the classes that don't have a AdditionalStuff. So 
abstract class A { 
    public AdditionalStuff getAdditionalStuff() {
        return null;
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

The classic "Text book method" would be the Visitor Pattern.

First, you need to define a visitor interface:

```
interface AVisitor<T> {
      T visitA1(A1 a1);
      T visitA2(A2 a2);
      T visitA3(A3 a3);
}
```

Then you need to extend your `A` class by an abstract method to recieve visitors:

```
abstract class A {
      ...

      public <T> abstract T recieve(AVisitor<T> visitor);
}
```

And your classes `A1`, `A2`, and `A3` need the implementation for the recieve methods:

```
class A1 extends A {
      ...
      public <T> T recieve(AVisitor<T> visitor) {
          return visitor.visitA1(this);
      }
}

class A2 extends A {
      ...
      public <T> T recieve(AVisitor<T> visitor) {
          return vistor.visitA2(this);
      }
}

class A3 extends A {
      ...
      public <T> T recieve(AVisitor<T> visitor) {
          return visitor.visitA3(this);
      }
}
```

And finally you must define the different `visit` Methods in your implementation class:

```
class Implementation implements AVisitor<AdditionalStuff> {

      void ... () {
          List<A> aList;
          ....

          for (A instance : aList) {
              AdditionalStuff aS = instance.recieve(this);
              aS.function();
          }
      }

      public AdditionalStuff visitA1(A1 a1) {
          return new AdditionalStuffForA1();
      }

      public AdditionalStuff visitA2(A2 a2) {
          return new AdditionalStuffForA2();
      }

      public AdditionalStuff visitA3(A3 a3) {
          return new AdditionalStuffForA3();
      }
}
```

This method has the advantage that your A, A1, A2 and A3 classes don't need any knowledge about these `AdditionalStuff`-classes. The disadvantage is when you need a fourth class A4, you have to add a `visitA4` method to the interface ... and in every single class which implements this `AVisitor` interface. (EDIT: But in difference to your `if (... instanceof ...) else if (... instanceof ...)` methods: The visitor approach would guarantee that you do not miss a special instance check. If you forget to add an implementation for handling your A4 classes, the compiler will tell it to you.
Edit: Fix code of Implementation class

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two good approaches.  Both are variations on the "factory" design pattern.

Approach 1 is to make the `A` classes responsible for creating instances of `AdditionalStuff` subtypes.

```
abstract class A {
    abstract AdditionalStuff makeAdditionalStuff();
    ...
}

class A1 extends class A {
    AdditionalStuff makeAdditionalStuff() {
        return new AdditionalStuffForA1();
    ...
}

class Implementation {
    List<A> aList; 
    .... //add A1, A2, A3 to aList

    for (A instance: aList) {
        instance.getAdditionalStuff().function()
    }
}
```

Approach 2 is to abstract out the instanceOf tests into a factory method:

```
AdditionalStuff getAdditionalStuff(A instance) {
    if (instance instanceOf A1) {
        return new AdditionalStuffForA1();
    } else if(instance instanceOf A2) {
        return new AdditionalStuffForA2();
    } else {
        return new AdditionalStuffForA3();
    }
}
```

or better:

```
AdditionalStuff getAdditionalStuff(A instance) {
    if (instance instanceOf A1) {
        return new AdditionalStuffForA1();
    } else if (instance instanceOf A2) {
        return new AdditionalStuffForA2();
    } else if (instance instanceOf A3) {
        return new AdditionalStuffForA3();
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("not implemented");
    }
}
```

You can replace the `if instanceof` tests with a `switch`, and switch on the class name for `instance`.  But for a small number of subclasses, there is little to be gained by doing that.  (IMO)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to make sensible suggestions without understand what your code is actually meant to do but I'd look into the factory pattern, i.e. provide a factory for each `AdditionalStuff` subclass, register it in some map and look it up via instance's class:

```
interface AdditionalStuffFactory {
  AdditionalStuff create();
}

class AdditionalStuffA1Factory implements AdditionalStuffFactory { 
  public AdditionalStuff create() {
    return new AdditionalStuffForA1();
  }
}
```

Then you have a `Map<Class<? extends A>, AdditionalStuffFactory>` somewhere, which would get filled with factory instances, e.g. `registry.put(A1.class, new AdditionalStuffA1Factory() );`

Your loop would then look like this:

```
 for (A instance: aList) {
   AdditionalStuff aS = registry.get(instance.getClass()).create();
   aS.function();
 }
```

Of course there are further optimizations, e.g. having "registry" delegate the calls thus getting something like `registry.createFor(instance)` but you should get the point.

Addition another `AdditionalStuff` would then require the following:

- creating the additional class (you always do that)
- creating a factory for that class (unless you can provide for some generic factory)
- register the new factory in your registry (that could be done via some lookup mechanism, e.g. via CDI, but I'll not get deeper into this here)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following.

First of all avoid using inheritance if you don't have to. For example your `AdditionalStuff` only defines a contract the method `function` which needs to implemented by the various classes you have. This can altered to be an `interface` instead of an `abstract` class.

With this in hand just change the list to hold the various interface implementations e.g:

```
List<SomeInterface> list = new ArrayList<>;
Collections.addAll(list, new ClassA(), new ClassB());
```

then just iterate through all of them in a single line and do:

```
list.forEach(SomeInterface::function);
```

This way you'll avoid the intricate inheritance (which is uneeded here), as well as the introspection and everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Use interfaces!

In Java 8 or higher, interfaces can have default method implementation.

You can define:

```
public interface AdditionalStuff {

    void function(Object... params);
}

public interface AdditionalStuffForA1 extends AdditionalStuff {

    default void function(Object... params) {
        //do something with params here
        System.out.println("implementation for A1");
    }
}

public interface AdditionalStuffForA2 extends AdditionalStuff {

    default void function(Object... params) {
        //do something with params here
        System.out.println("implementation for A2");
    }
}
```

And create your classes with the proper interface:

```
public abstract class A implements AdditionalStuff {

}

public class A1 extends A implements AdditionalStuffForA1 {

}

public class A2 extends A implements AdditionalStuffForA2 {

}
```

With this execution:

```
List<A> aList = new ArrayList<>();

aList.add(new A1());
aList.add(new A2());
aList.add(new A2());

for (A a : aList) {
     a.function(23, 45, "string...");
}
```

Will print:

```
implementation for A1
implementation for A2
implementation for A2
```

The additional behavior can be controlled with the parameter (Object ... params)

Answer (score 0):

the own method on the abstract or interface implementation, can validate it self, preventing many if, using just one if inside every one of this implementations. adding this on [architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51656020/9950567) from @Lup.